Why does the Antidetect browser keep the finished session from the account longer than just the saved tokens from the session (cookies, Bearer, etc.)?
Why does the antidetect browser keep the finished session from the account longer than just the saved tokens from the session (cookies, Bearer, etc.) ? Why can I go to the antidetect browser profile even after a month and continue working from where I left off, but if even after two days I try to make an http request using the stored tokens and cookies, they have time to expire and I fail?
Спрашивал у чата GPT:-)
